# How to make the product price as a specific amount

Tags: plugin

I want to make the price of all product to 100 in the cart. I have created a plugin and tried using it but I was not able to change the price value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to change the price of all products to "1"

```
public function afterGetPrice(Product $subject, $result)
{
   $this->logger->debug('after get price'); //to check if its working
   $result = 1;
   return $result;
}
```